# Spark Java: how to register a UDAF function using the new Aggregator<IN, BUF, OUT>

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-sedona

**I'm using Java** and can register an UDF function, and it works:

```
UDF1<Geometry, String> stGetUTMZone = new StGetUTMZone();
sparkSession.udf().register("ST_GetUTMZone", stGetUTMZone, DataTypes.StringType);
```

However, when I try registering an UDAF function, besides no compilation error is found, I get a runtime error due to datatype mismatch:

```
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;

sparkSession.udf().register("ST_Safe_Union_Aggr",
        functions.udaf(new StSafeUnionAggregator(), Encoders.javaSerialization(Geometry.class)));
```

I tried also using `Encoders.kryo()` and `Encoders.bean()` with no success.

Is this the correct way for registering an UDAF function? I know Spark is written in Scala however I'd like to avoid rewriting our jobs in Scala.

I need to register an UDAF function in Java and tried using the `functions.udaf()` (Scala API) but it doesn't work as in Scala.
In Scala I would register the UDAF function using `functions.udaf(myFunc)` but in Java I cannot call it without passing 2 parameters.

This is the `StSafeUnionAggregator` definition:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;

// An example of my UDAF (using Aggregator, not the deprecated UserDefinedFunction)
public class StSafeUnionAggregator extends Aggregator<Geometry, Geometry, Geometry> {
    ...

    // Specifies the Encoder for the intermediate value type
    @Override
    public Encoder<Geometry> bufferEncoder() {
        return Encoders.javaSerialization(Geometry.class);
    }

    // Specifies the Encoder for the final output value type
    @Override
    public Encoder<Geometry> outputEncoder() {
        return Encoders.javaSerialization(Geometry.class);
    }

    ...
}
```

And this is the error message:

```
Error: 
cannot resolve 'ST_Safe_Union_Aggr(geom_field)' due to data type mismatch: 
argument 1 requires binary type, however, 'tmptableincomingdata.geom_field' 
is of array<tinyint> type.; line 1 pos 79;
```

Comment: Can you include the `StSafeUnionAggregator` class declaration and the exact error message?

Comment: I added the requested info; by the way, I created another question with more details but it got no comments or answers yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74183571/how-to-register-a-new-user-defined-aggregate-function-with-custom-type-encoder-t